# Get the time in seconds in this form d.ddd

Tags: python

I want to get the elapsed time in the form of seconds in this form `d.ddddddd`, e.g., 5.656 seconds. When using `time.time()`, the value becomes very large, something like 1485831617.19 which has 10 values. How can modify the following way:

```
start = time.time()
time.sleep(2)
elapsed = time.time()
pretty = '{:.3f}'.format(elapsed)
print pretty
```

This still print something like 1485832865.471. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: it should be `elapsed = time.time() - start`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
`pretty = "%.3f" % (elapsed)`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I got this 1485832705.843 .. Still not quite right

Comment: @Donald: That's an unadjusted value straight from `time.time()`. Doesn't look like you actually calculated and used `elapsed`, looks like you used `start` or `now` without subtracting.

Comment: @Donald: Yeah, your original code was correctly calculating `elapsed`, I have no idea why you switched to broken code, it just made it worse. `elapsed = time.time() - start` would get you the value you presumably want.